# "The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments" error

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, mouselistener

I wanted to create a `JFrame` where it prints out on the console: "It works!!" when you click a `JButton`. Below is the code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CurrentlyMajorCodesCompiler extends JFrame {

public static void main (String args[]) {
CurrentlyMajorCodes CMC = new CurrentlyMajorCodes();

CMC.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}

public class CurrentlyMajorCodes extends JFrame {

private JButton ClickSpeedTest;
private tensCPS TCPS;

public CurrentlyMajorCodes () {
    super("Major Code Compiler");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ClickSpeedTest = new JButton("Click Speed Test");
    add(ClickSpeedTest);

    ClickSpeedTest.addActionListener(new MouseAdapter () {
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("It works!!");
        }
    });

    setSize(250, 250);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

However, at: `ClickSpeedTest.addActionListener`, it gives me an error saying:

```
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type 
    AbstractButton is not applicable for 
    the arguments (new MouseAdapter(){})`
```

I don't understand what it's trying to communicate, because I never used an `AbstractButton` in the code, and don't know what it even is. Can someone please help?

Comment: JButton extends AbstractButton, which has the method addActionListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseListener is different from ActionListener. You need to use the later

```
ClickSpeedTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("It works!!");
    }
});
```

Comment: What are the differences? MouseListener encapsulates all the things the mouse causes (move, drag, click, enter, exit). ActionListener is for clicking buttons, but it is also used for initiating the action from the Keyboard or from some other input

Answer (score 1):

Method [addActionListener()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) in class `AbstractButton` takes a single parameter, namely an instance of a class that implements interface [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). Class `JButton` extends `AbstractButton` and therefore inherits this method.

Now look at class [MouseAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html). You will see that it **does not** implement interface `ActionListener` and therefore is not suitable as a parameter for method `addActionListener()`.

For the requirement described in your question, I recommend creating your own implementation of interface `ActionListener`. The following is similar to the code you posted and uses an anonymous inner class to implement interface `ActionListener`:

```java
ClickSpeedTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("It works!!");
    }
});
```

Note that the above `actionPerformed()` method will be invoked whenever the button `ClickSpeedTest` is activated, whether via the mouse or the keyboard or even via java code. (Refer to method [doClick()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick--) in class `AbstractButton`.)

If you are using Java 8 or above, then `ActionListener` is a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html#package.description), i.e. an interface that contains precisely one abstract method and hence you can implement it using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) which means you could also use the following code:

```java
ClickSpeedTest.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("It works!!"));
```